# Create a column that's a combination of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns, and I want to create a new column as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=['A','B','C'])
cols = df.abs().idxmax(axis = 1)
cols
0    C
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
dtype: object
```

I want to create a column `D` that takes the value of `C` at index 0, `A` at index 1, etc.. In other words, `D` takes values from the appropriate column as per the object `cols`. I'm sure I can loop through the indices and pick the columns, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
print (df)
          A         B         C
0 -0.217679  0.821455  1.481278
1  1.331864 -0.361865  0.685609
2  0.573761  0.287728 -0.235634
3  0.953490 -1.689625 -0.344943
4  0.016905 -0.514984  0.244509

df['D'] = df.lookup(df.index, cols)
print (df)
          A         B         C         D
0 -0.217679  0.821455  1.481278  1.481278
1  1.331864 -0.361865  0.685609  1.331864
2  0.573761  0.287728 -0.235634  0.573761
3  0.953490 -1.689625 -0.344943 -1.689625
4  0.016905 -0.514984  0.244509 -0.514984
```